# How to calculate growth rates up and down from a local maxima?

Tags: r, ecology, extreme-value, symmetry

**Problem:** I am currently doing my Msc-thesis on rodent population dynamics. One of my aims is look at symmetry in oscillation topography. For this I want to calculate the growth rates up and down from peaks in a 100 year time series.

**Attempt:** My initial thought was to identify local maxima and then use the points before and after the max to calculate growth rates. The aim is to show that when the difference in growth rates pre- and post-peak is smaller there is more symmetry.

I have used this function to find the positions of the  local maxima:

```
localMaximalem <- function(lemming1) {
# Use -Inf instead if x is numeric (non-integer)
y <- diff(c(-.Machine$integer.max, lemming1)) > 0L
rle(y)$lengths
y <- cumsum(rle(y)$lengths)
y <- y[seq.int(1L, length(y), 2L)]
if (lemming1[[1]] == lemming1[[2]]) {
    y <- y[-1]
}
y
}
```

It seems to give me reasonable numbers.

**Question:** However, how can I then incorporate the calculation of growth rates?

I am thinking I should index it by for instance I and use `localMaximalem[i-1]` and `localMaximalem[i+1]` and use the traditional growth rate equation. I am, however, very unsure of how to code this.

Or is my thinking completely off?